# Android Native Activity - Call Java method

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, native-activity

I've been trying for a while to call a java method from c++, I am able to do it successfully with an Activity class but with a NativeActivity, it crashes when calling CallVoidMethod. GetMethodID is able to find it, it returns an address. env & vm objects are valid & are populated from android_main(). Is it possible that it simply won't work with a native activity class?

Cpp: (edited)

```
void SendNotification() {

    JavaVM* lJavaVM = main_activity->vm;
    JNIEnv* lJNIEnv = main_activity->env;

    JavaVMAttachArgs lJavaVMAttachArgs;
    lJavaVMAttachArgs.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    lJavaVMAttachArgs.name = "NativeThread";
    lJavaVMAttachArgs.group = NULL;

    jint lResult = lJavaVM->AttachCurrentThread(&lJNIEnv, &lJavaVMAttachArgs);
    if (lResult == JNI_ERR)
        return;

    jobject lNativeActivity = main_activity->clazz;
    jclass ClassNativeActivity = lJNIEnv->GetObjectClass(main_activity->clazz);
    jmethodID _method = lJNIEnv->GetMethodID(ClassNativeActivity, "SendNotification", "()V");

    lJNIEnv->CallVoidMethod(lNativeActivity, _method);

    lJavaVM->DetachCurrentThread();
}
```

Java:

```
package com.thor.kalen;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.NativeActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends NativeActivity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    } // End of public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

    public void SendNotification() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Alert").setMessage("").setNeutralButton("Close", null).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**com.thor.kalen.MainActivity.SendNotification()** Java method should be called for a *jobject* of class **com.thor.kalen.MainActivity**, not a *jclass* of this object: it's not a *static* method:

```
main_activity->env->CallVoidMethod(main_activity.clazz, _method)
```

Note the comment in **native_activity.h**:

> ```
> /**
>  * The NativeActivity object handle.
>  *
>  * IMPORTANT NOTE: This member is mis-named. It should really be named 
>  * 'activity' instead of 'clazz', since it's a reference to the
>  * NativeActivity instance created by the system for you.
>  * 
>  * We unfortunately cannot change this without breaking NDK
>  * source-compatibility.
> */
> jobject clazz;
> ```

Also, you can only **show()** an AlertDialog from the Main (UI) thread. Your C++ code suggests that you do you from a background thread.

If this code executes on the main thread, then

```
main_activity->vm->DetachCurrentThread()
```

should be removed. **AttachThread()** can be removed, too, but it's a NOP when called on a thread that is already attached.

Comment: I tried replacing the alert dialog with int x=0; and it still crashes, looks like it doesn't even get there.

Comment: Also, i am calling it from android_main.

Comment: You're right! I got the object and class mixed up, it's working now, thank you so much!